# relative path js and css not found in 404html nginx static web site

Tags: html, nginx

I want to create static web site in nginx.
I need a 404.html but it have some js and css link ,path is root, blow

```
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="js/custom.js" rel="stylesheet">
```

nginx

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
```

when i access a not exist file url like http://www.test.com/xxx is ok 404.html correct show.

but when i access url with like http://www.test.com/xxx/xxx, i get a wrong page, open console, i found my css and js path changed http://www.test.com/xxx/custom.css

I see if i change js and css file relative path to absolte path.
but i need relative path.
I expect get correct 404.html with its js and css file with any url when 404 and js/css use relative.

How to config nginx or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not to change in nginx

nginx still

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
```

change html

```
css/custom.css
```

to

```
/css/custom.css
```

same to js files

this resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using a location in nginx configuration

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
           root /usr/share/nginx/html;
           internal;
}
```

Comment: thanks,i try it. my root not /usr/share/nginx/html, so i change path to my root path and i restart my nginx ,my js/css in 404html still show Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()